# How do i acces a list that is not connected to my class

Tags: c#, list, object

[image]

Above picture is a picture of my class diagram. However i have a problem. In my OrderForm class i would like to display the property shippingtime of all the parts in an order that arent in stock. However i cannot acces the warehouse in a convenient way. I cant just make an object since its stock would differ from the one acctually used by workshop, and i cant make the availableparts list static since that would mean every future warehouse would all have the same stock.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply pass the WareHouse through to Order?
You could even go as far as extracting an interface, something like IStockManager that publishes the GetStock method implement it on your WareHouse and then pass it into order.

There are many ways to connect these classes, some are less coupled than others and it depends on your architecture, but I think the way I mentioned above is fine for your needs.

**Edit:**

As requested here's an example of a very basic "mediator" class.
It's not exactly compliant with the pattern, but it should be enough to put you on the right track.

Basically the mediator in your case needs to initialize all the objects, and publish methods which you want other classes to have access to.

```
public class Mediator
{
   private readonly WareHouse _wareHouse;
   private readonly OrderForm _orderForm;

   public Mediator()
   {
      _wareHouse = new WareHouse();
      _orderForm = new OrderForm(this);
   }

   public int GetStock(Part part)
   {
      return _wareHouse.GetStock(part);
   }
}
```

Basically the mediator hosts methods that are accessible to all classes that know of the mediator. As you can see we pass the Mediator to the constructor of the OrderForm, so the OrderForm now knows of the Mediator and its method(GetStock).

```
public class OrderForm
{
   private readonly Mediator _mediator;

   public OrderForm(Mediator mediator)
   {
      _mediator = mediator;
      var stock = _mediator.GetStock(yourPart);
      // Now you can call WareHouse.GetStock(yourPart) through the 
         mediator
   }
}
```

I don't know if calling this class a mediator is really correct, since it doesn't fit the pattern exactly, but it's sufficient for a simple application, and you can [read up](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/04/30/the-mediator-pattern-in-net-core-part-1-whats-a-mediator/) on it if you wanted to implement it properly.

Comment: if i passed the warehouse to order, wouldnt that mean declaring a new object of warehouse in the order class?

Edit:
That would probably work by just declaring a warehouse like this wouldnt it:
private WareHouse warehouse;

Comment: You can have a class that creates all instances necessary and then pass them through the constructor.  If you wanted to know more about this kind of process you can look up dependency injection. The easiest way to achieve that would be to have a class that's called on start of your application, have it create ```new WareHouse```, and then ```new OrderForm(WareHouse)```. If you wanted to limit the WareHouse access that ```OrderForm``` has  you could create the interface I mentioned before, and have ```OrderForm``` accept ```IStockManager``` as a parameter in its constructor.

Comment: Other way could be to simply have a "Mediator" class, that has references to all objects, and is passed to all objects that need it. This class would be a connector between your classes. This way you can do something like this: ```Mediator.GetStock(itemid)``` and the Mediator would call ```WareHouse.GetStock(itemId)```. This way the OrderForm would have no idea about the WareHouse and would only know about Mediator and the methods it owns.

Comment: As I said there are many ways to achieve this, and it's up to architectural decisions. In case you look up the terms I mentioned above, there are packages that do exactly that, but it's not neccessary to use them if your application is simple, you can implement these patterns yourself.

Comment: Ive spend the whole day on a mediator class, but it doesnt really work. Could you describe in code how a simple mediator class would look?